# Best way to save and utilize mysql database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

So i'm looking for an efficient way to work with the sql data i'm going to store. 
For now it's pretty simple, i have a table with multiple attributes that i want to collect via js. 
I don't know if putting this into an HTML table would be the best option, i don't think so since i believe it would make things harder to get rows with specific attribute. 
The information i want to extract from the database would look like this :

Event1 ID1 start end duration week attribute1 .... attributeX 
Event2 ID2 start end duration week attribute1 .... attributeX 
..

If the user asks for events from week n°3 i want to connect to the database only once, get all the events from that week, and then i have to process that data so that specific events with specific attribute values would appear at some place in the page.
Do you guys know what's the best way to store the data in order to do that kind of thing ?

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP side you can store your data like that :

```
$array = [];
        $array[] = [
            'event' =>Event1,
            'id' => ID1,
            'start' => start,
            'end' => end, 
            'duration' => duration, 
            'week' => week, 
            'attributres' => [attribute1, ...., attributeX]
        ];
```

Then you should use the `json_encode` method to send it back to the AJAX. And like that you should have a nice and pretty JS Object that you can use to do hat you want.

Comment: I already have the page set in php, but that wasn't the question, i'm looking forward to see in what kind of object i should store the responseText from the server...

Comment: Sorry I did not understood your question. I'm not sure I still not sure that I understand your question but are you asking about the data structure you should use ?

Comment: Yes in what type of object i should store the server data to make efficient use of it in javascript. (once it has been already been treated by php)

Comment: yes already thought of it, but i was hoping for something new. anyways thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just as a memo for me, and eventually to help people out. 
Found out this is the best way to do things yesterday :

`while($row=$query->fetch()){
    $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);`

Where $data is the array that will contain all the sql informations like so :

$data['0']['nameEvent'], $data['0']['id'] ..... $data['0']['attributeX'] 
...
$data['n']['nameEvent'] ....

This type of storage is very convenient and makes it easy to fully mess with the DB informations as i wish.